# Declare Pointer in Header results in Access Violation

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm quite new to C++, so bear with me. In my header file, I have the following class declared:

```
#include "AC_Airframe_A330.h"

class AC_App
{
public:
    AC_App();
    ~AC_App();

    HRESULT Initialize();

    AC_Airframe_A330 * m_Airframe;
};
```

In my C++ file, I use the following code to start the program, and begin to create my pointers:

```
#include "AC_App.h"

AC_App * m_App;

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int )
{
    HeapSetInformation(NULL, HeapEnableTerminationOnCorruption, NULL, 0);

    if (SUCCEEDED(CoInitialize(NULL)))
    {
        {

            if (SUCCEEDED(m_App->Initialize()))
            {
                m_App->RunMessageLoop();
            }
        }
        CoUninitialize();
    }

    return 0;
}

HRESULT AC_App::Initialize()
{   
    //AC_Airframe_A330 * m_Airframe;
    m_Airframe = new AC_Airframe_A330();

    m_Airframe->Startup_State();

<snip>
```

As you can see, I have put the pointers in the Header file, which generates an Access Violation Writing Location and an address at this line

```
m_Airframe = new AC_Airframe_A330();
```

If I comment the Header line out, and uncomment the line in my Initialize function, it works. Why is this? I'd like the m_Airframe object to be available to other things outside of the Initialize function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see where `m_App` is used - but I don't see where it's ever assigned a value. You are calling a method on an uninitialized pointer, one pointing to random garbage.

Comment: I originally had the line as AC_App * m_App = 0; to NULL it out, but it didn't seem to make a difference?

Comment: @Igor: His `m_App` is at global scope and will be _default initialised_ to zero. So a crash anyway when dereferenced.

Comment: Please tell me this is a flight simulator and not an actual airplane software

Comment: @Amxx fear not it is for FS use! The program has lots of variables running all over the shop and others who have gone before me have used this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using any reference to `m_App` you must allocate it with `new`:

```
m_App = new AC_App();
```

Comment: Aha! I thought it would be something like this. Thanks Zac. I inserted this line into the WinMain and now it works :) I would upvote, but my reputation isn't good enough.

Comment: I would recommend replacing AC_App * with std::unique_ptr<AC_App> and AC_Airframe_A330 * with std::unique_ptr<AC_Airframe_A330> and using std::make_unique instead of "new".  Change to std::shared_ptr if needed.  This makes it somewhat harder to forget to delete the memory after allocation.

Answer (score 3):

Pointer `m_App` was initialized by null pointer constant.

```
AC_App * m_App;
```

Thus when member function `Initialize` is called

```
if (SUCCEEDED(m_App->Initialize()))
```

it tries to access its data member at invalid address

```
m_Airframe = new AC_Airframe_A330();
```

and error "access violation" is issued.

You have to allocate (or define) an object that will be referred to by this pointer.

Comment: Ok this makes sense, but how do I therefore create an m_App object that contains everything? I appreciate this might be a stupid question, but i'm finding it difficult to get my head around pointers.